# "RESOLVED" two forms one submit button error | IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: django

[RESOLVED] I FOUND THE SOLUTION AND UPDATED WITH THE WORKING CODE BELOW

I'm trying to submit two forms with one button.
I check a few other posts in here, but I'm not sure if the code below is the correct.

```
def cars_detail(request, car_id):
  car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
  profile_form = ProfileForm()
  booking_form = BookingForm()
  
  return render(request, 'cars/detail.html', { 'car': car, 'booking_form': booking_form, 'profile_form': profile_form })


def addbooking(request, car_id): 
  if request.method == 'POST':
    
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    booking_form = BookingForm(request.POST)
    print(request.POST)
    if profile_form.is_valid() or booking_form.is_valid(): 
      # do stuff here
      # form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        new_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        new_profile.car_id = car_id
        new_profile.user_id = request.user.id
        new_profile.save()
      # do stuff here
      # form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        new_booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
        new_booking.car_id = car_id
        new_booking.user_id = request.user.id
        new_booking.save()
    return redirect('detail', car_id=car_id)
  
  else:
    profile_form = ProfileForm(prefix="profile_form")
    booking_form = BookingForm(prefix="booking_form")
```

Comment: `if profile_form.is_valid() or booking_form.is_valid(): ` this statement cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have no code in the block after the “if”.
If there’s nothing to do in that instance negate the condition and remove the “else”

But do you want to reset both forms if only one of them is invalid? You might want this instead

```
if !profile_form.is_valid():
    profile_form = Profile_form(prefix="profile_form")

if !booking_form.is_valid():
    booking_form = Booking_form(prefix="booking_form")
```

Comment: Right, my bad. This two functions take care of these forms, I have to merge then in that conditional, but I have no idea how

Comment: @DavidCibin - I'm glad you got it working. However it's better to add your own answer showing your new code than change your question - as now it doesn't look like you have a problem :) You can even [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as the solution if you want. Once you have added your answer roll back the edit on the question so it shows the original code.

Comment: @DavidCibin - and you don't need to put "resolved" in the question title. A question is resolved when you accept an answer by clicking the tick to the left of it.